# Nginx L4 Proxy Works with HTTPS but not with HTTP

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I have the following configuration as L4 proxy over Nginx and everything works fine.

```
  stream {
 

    
    map $ssl_preread_server_name $name {
    hostnames;
    .ipchicken.com          $ssl_preread_server_name;
    .bbc.com                $ssl_preread_server_name;
    .bbc.co.uk              $ssl_preread_server_name;
    .bbci.co.uk             $ssl_preread_server_name;
    .neverssl.com           $ssl_preread_server_name;  #<-------
    
}


server {

    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    listen 443;
    ssl_preread on;
    proxy_connect_timeout 5s;
    proxy_pass $name:$server_port;
}
```

But when HTTP site is requested, like "http://neverssl.com/" Nginx is not responding.
Any idea for this issue?

Comment: `http://` scheme uses TCP port 80, while your server block is listening on port 443.

Comment: @IvanShatsky. Dear Ivan, Thanks for your reply. to be honest I want both HTTP and HTTPS to be routed through my proxy. Last time you have helped me to correct my configuration for HTTPS. I would be thankful if can guide me on how to have both configured in the same configuration file.

Comment: @IvanShatsky i think there should be something configured in ssl_preread_server_name;,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far a I know `ssl_preread` directive works only with HTTPS protocol. I don't know how to get HTTP `Host` header value in the `ngx_stream_core_module`. You can try to use an additional `server` block in the **http** context like shown [here](https://serverfault.com/a/298808/498657):

```
http {
    ...
    map $http_host $proxy {
        hostnames;
        .neverssl.com    $http_host;
        ...
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        location / {
            if ($proxy = '') { return 403; } # Return HTTP 403 Forbidden for unlisted domains
            proxy_set_header Host $proxy;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_connect_timeout 5s;
            proxy_pass http://$proxy;
        }
    }
}

stream {
    ... # stream configuration for HTTPS port 443 here
}
```

There is no need to use `$server_port` variable at the stream server block, you are listening on the 443 port only, so you can just use `proxy_pass $name:443;`